# loop the function over dates and export files in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a function which do the iterative proportional fitting (raking). It needs data and config file as an input and produces two outputs. The sample below is a test for a single date run.

I am wondering how can I put the whole process inside a loop over dates. I have data and config file for each date (date exist in the file name) and I need to produce outputs per date. So lets say I have 30 days data_XXXXX.txt filea and 30 days config_XXXX.txt filea.

```
#read data and config for one day
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,'data_15062020.txt'))
config = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,'config_15062020.txt'))

  #Run function  
new_config,  KPI_stat_summary = run_my_function(data, config)

#export output
new_config.to_csv("new_config_15062020.csv")
KPI_stat_summary.to_csv("KPI_stat_summary_15062020.csv")
```

Comment: Cannot you use `glob()` to get the data files, and then for each of them read the related config file (or the other way round) and call your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over dates, you can also loop over your files in the format **data_XXXXX.txt** with help of [**`glob`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module, and produce outputs per file.

So first using **`glob.glob`** function over pattern `data_*.txt`, get all data files you need to apply your function on. Corresponding **config** files can be read by replacing `data` with `config` in the filename. Apply your function, and produce outputs accordingly by constructing their names too:

```
import glob
all_data_files = [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'data_*.txt'))]
    

for file in all_data_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file))
    config = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file.replace('data','config')))
    
    
    new_config,  KPI_stat_summary = run_my_function(data, config)
    
    #export output
    new_config.to_csv(file.replace('data','new_config').replace('.txt','.csv'))
    KPI_stat_summary.to_csv(file.replace('data','KPI_stat_summary').replace('.txt','.csv'))
```